# HTML onclick div id goto both href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the .onclick function bound to a (div id) which will take it to another page once it is clicked ( onclick="location.href='homepage.html';" )

```
<div id="google">
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
</div>
```

Once the link in the  is clicked it will open a blank page and load google.com but on the original page i need it to go to homepage.html or refresh either one.

Comment: It is not possible technically. Once the page changes to a different domain, you lose control over it.

Comment: Is this supposed to happen in the same window/tab? Then it's not possible. Otherwise add `target="_blank"` to your `a` tag

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Timeout for this.

HTML:

```
<div onclick="setTimeout(location.href='YOUR-URL-HERE';, 5000)" id="google">
<a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">google</a>
</div>
```

```css
#google{width:100px; height:200px;background-color:red;}
```

```html
    <div onclick="setTimeout(location.href='www.houjebek.nl';, 5000)" id="google">
    <a href="www.google.com">google</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to add `target="_blank"` to the `<a>` if not the timeout will no take effect.

Comment: he doesnt want there to be a timeout on the <a> right?